# How do I use chapters with Beamer?

Tags: beamer, sectioning, chapters

I have no idea how to insert chapters in a Beamer presentation.

Comment: Why do you need chapters? Why not just sections? It's all the same (as in, it's sectional units/divisions within some document), isn't it?

Comment: Beamer does not have chapters. Depending on what you need them for, you can use lectures, parts or sections instead